# decryption and encryption password in yii

Tags: database, encryption, passwords, yii2

It is my code:

```
//save user in DB
$email='user1@email.com';
$username='user1';
$password='user1';
echo 'No hashed password='.$password.'<br>';
$user= new User();
$user->email=$email;
$user->username=$username;
$user->password=Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password);
echo 'Hashed password='.$user->password;
echo '<br>';
$user->save();

//check user
$password2 ='user1';
$password2=Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($password2); //do hash
echo 'Hashed password2='.$password2;
$check_user=User::find()->where(['email' => $email])->one();
if($check_user) { //if user found
    if (Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password2, $check_user->password)) {
        echo  'Yes';
    } else {
        echo 'No';
    }
}
```

I save my data(email,username,password) in DB . And when I want to check my password I always get **NO**.
How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate a new hash when checking the password. Just compare the information (`$password2`)  with your saved hash (`$check_user->password`).

```
//check user
$password2 ='user1';
echo 'password2 = ' . $password2 . '<br />';

$check_user=User::find()->where(['email' => $email])->one();

if($check_user) //if user found
{
    if (Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password2, $check_user->password)) {
        echo  'Yes';
    } else {
        echo 'No';
    }
}
```

You can find more information in the docs: [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-passwords.html) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html).